# WooCommerce display field depending on category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, categories

My e-commerce inventory mainly contains street signs which i added some custom code to display the dimensions (H x W x L) of my signs in single product

However I have a few jackets that don't require dimensions.

I cannot find what fields or an example of an IF statement that will only let me display certain fields for a specific category.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that dimensions is set in *product data*.

```
$meta = get_postmeta($post_id);
if ($meta['_width'][0] && $meta['_length'][0] && $meta['_height'][0]) {
    //show the dimensions
}
```

Comment: I'd like to filter this based on what category its under. Example: If the category is "jacket", don't display the dimensions